# Convert NSDate time in milliseconds as Int32 and Int64 in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate

I have a Swift NSDate:

```
var date:NSDate()
```

and want to get the milliseconds since 1970 as Int32:

```
let time: Int32 = Int32(date.timeIntervalSince1970*1000)

let time: Int64 = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970*1000)
```

**Is this the correct way to do it?**

Answer (score 4):

Please not Int32.

Int32 has values up to 2^31. That's milliseconds, so about 2 million seconds. That's not even a month. Your code stopped working before February 1970.

Comment: So you recommend to use Int64 all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

```
var date: NSDate()
```

Then you would use:

```
let time = Int32(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
```

(`timeIntervalSince1970` is a property on an `NSDate` instance.)

Comment: @confile: No, neither of the ways you asked about work. My solution might be a bit off (not on a Mac right now), but I believe it should work.

Comment: I had a spelling error while copying the code. I think you have the same as I have?

Comment: @confile: I don't know (I'm not on a Mac right now). What is the error?

Comment: There is no error I just want to confirm that I am doing it right.

Comment: FYI, if you are planning to run the app in 32-bit devices like iPhone 5, then the app will crash , so you should be consider using Int which will take the size depending upon the platform